# How much did he pay for the car?

Tags: mathematics, calculation-puzzle

A man withdrew half the money that was in his bank account to buy a second-hand car, then sold the car two weeks later, receiving only three-quarters of the price he had paid for it. When he paid the money back into the bank account he found his bank balance was £600 less than it had been originally.

How much did he pay for the car?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

He paid

> **£2400** for the car.
>
>  Originally his bank held £4800.
>  After buying the car, he had £2400 in the bank.
>  He sold the car for £1800.
>  The bank now has £4200.
>  Which is £600 less than when he started.

Comment: Please don't post solutions to please-do-my-algebra-homework calculation puzzles. It only encourages them.

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan oh ok, that was indeed how I solved it, without showing the working.

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan hmm, I didn't realise it was homework, that is usually more obvious to me on other SE sites I visit.

Comment: Full disclosure: It was a puzzle on the back of a match box that my grandfather had been struggling with for days. Apologies for being "off-topic", and thank you for helping him solve it, @WeatherVane.

Comment: I was only guessing that it was homework. Turns out I was kinda-right :-). My apologies, @Kelling, for being one notch too cynical.